# Como evitar mutar la propiedad readonly de un componente

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual dibuja un html recorriendo una lista de archivos, el <b-form-input que esta en readonly necesito ponerlo en ocasiones en modo de edicion. por lo que en la funcion EditName usando refs trate de poner la propiedad readonly a false y me da el famoso error de mutation.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui mi codigo

```
 <div class="row" v-for="(file,index) in files" :key="file.code">
<div class="col-md-1 align-self-center" style="text-align: center;">   
    <b-icon icon="eye" aria-hidden="true" v-on:click="OpenDocument(file)" style="cursor: hand;width: 20px; height: 20px;"></b-icon>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 align-self-center">
  <b-input-group size="sm" class="mt-2">
  <b-input-group-prepend is-text>
    <b-icon icon="brush" aria-hidden="true" v-on:click="EditName(file)"></b-icon>
  </b-input-group-prepend>
   <b-form-input v-model="file.name" :ref="file.code" readonly></b-form-input>   
</b-input-group>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
<MdEdit                               
   v-bind:TypeProp="'text'" 
   v-model="file.description"
   v-bind:isReadOnly="false">                                     
</MdEdit>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 align-items-start">
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" @click="removeFile(file)">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>    
</div>
```

Intente desde javascript cambiar la propiedad readonly asi:

```
this.$refs[file.code][0].readonly = false;
```

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Y porque no haces lo que te dice el error?